# After adding UIBezierPath to UILabel size not changing based on device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibezierpath

My Code

```
-(void)roundCornersWithCorner:(UIRectCorner)corners andRadius:(CGFloat)radius withView:(UILabel *)lable
{
CAShapeLayer * maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:lable.bounds byRoundingCorners:corners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)].CGPath;
lable.layer.mask = maskLayer;

[[lable layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -2)];
[[lable layer] setShadowOpacity:0.5f];
[[lable layer] setShadowRadius:2.0f];

}
```

Calling function :

```
[self roundCornersWithCorner: UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight andRadius:12 withView:myLabel];
```

[image]

Here trailing space is more compare to leading.

Leading and trailing of round corner image should be the same. How to set?

Comment: You sure if you don't call this function than your trailing and leading space will be fine? How are you setting frame? Is it auto layout constraint?

Comment: @ Sandeep Bhandari, I'm not calling this function anywhere and i fixed constraints in storyboard. i checked.

Comment: so basically this function isn't the culprit :D show us your constraints or if you are updating constraint value programmatically that as well

Comment: It is also recommended that set the width in a layer, not in UIBezierPath

Comment: @ Maulik Pandya, can you suggest the code

Comment: When `roundCornersWithCorner:` is called, check the frame of the label. Add didLayoutSubview, and check the frame again there of the label.